# Should you disclose any details when asked about your work permit?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, international

When seeking a job online in a country where you have a temporary work permit, should you tell about the permit to the potential employer? Should you mention the length of the permit or that you will require sponsorship when the permit expires?

Should the approach be different depending on the area? (e.g. USA, Canada, EU...)

Comment: Of course you have to. Not every company is ready (or willing) to provide sponsorship.

Comment: Yes you have to - but they will, of course, ask anyways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is simply unethical not to. A lot of companies or even teams within companies that sometimes do, can not offer sponsorships, and they will be at least a bit bothered by their employee suddenly dropping out.

Also, at least in the US, the onboarding process involves the HR verifiying your employment eligibility so it will come out even if you hide it.

Comment: It's not really about hiding it, it's about maximizing my chances to not be excluded at the start. I believe showing your skills first thus showing your value can change things,.

Comment: But @Cress, what you are doing is the opposite of maximizing your chances. Many places will drop you in the first screening process if you currently can’t work in their country. And, having once gotten permission it is usually easier to keep getting it so you are more likely to be able to keep working.